# Create Project using custom template via command line

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2019, code-generation, dotnet-cli

I created a custom multi template for visual studio that will be used across the organization and install on developers PCs. The problem is that if the template changes, it would require the developer to install the latest and if they fail to do it then they will create the application with the incorrect template.

My plan is to setup some devops workflow to accomplish this i.e. the creation of the project will be done without VS, worst case run a batch file that will copy the latest template across(from a share) and create the project.

My question is, is there and what is the command/s that I can call that would create the vs solution based on a custom template. The template takes the normal parameters i.e. project name, location and solutions name.

I will also be happy to write a c# win app to accomplish this task.
It's a .vstemplate file below

```
<VSTemplate Version="2.0.0" Type="ProjectGroup"xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/vstemplate/2005">
    <TemplateData>
        <Name>Integration Startup Template</Name>
        <Description>An example of a multi-project template</Description>
        <Icon>__TemplateIcon.png</Icon>
        <PreviewImage>__PreviewImage.png</PreviewImage>
        <ProjectType>CSharp</ProjectType>
        <LanguageTag>C#</LanguageTag>
        <PlatformTag>Windows</PlatformTag>
        <ProjectTypeTag>Web</ProjectTypeTag>
    </TemplateData>
....
```

I read up a little on [dotnet new](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-new), not sure what the short name would be and how to fill in the other details on the command such as solution name and location.

Thank you.

Comment: Have you completed the entire tutorial[(Tutorial: Create an item template)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tutorials/cli-templates-create-item-template)?